# How to surpass gradle wsimport task JDK 8 access restrictions?

Tags: gradle, java-8, wsimport

I have a wsimport task in my gradle build working fine until Java 7:

```
task wsimport {
    ext.destDir = file("${buildDir}/generated/java")
    ext.wsdlSrc = file("src/main/resources/schema/example/my.wsdl")
    ext.bindingSrc = file("src/main/resources/schema/example/bindings.xsd")
    outputs.dir destDir
    doLast {
        ant {
            destDir.mkdirs()
            taskdef(name: 'wsimport',
                classname: 'com.sun.tools.ws.ant.WsImport',
                classpath: configurations.jaxws.asPath)
            wsimport(keep: true,
                package: 'net.example.my',
                xnocompile: true,
                quiet: true,
                sourcedestdir: destDir,
                wsdl: wsdlSrc,
                binding: bindingSrc,
                encoding: "UTF-8"
            )
        }
    }
}
```

When switching to JDK 8 (build 1.8.0-b129) I get the following error:

```
java.lang.AssertionError: org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: ... schema_reference:
Failed to read schema document 'xjc.xsd', because 'file' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

Searching for the problem I found the following post (describing the problem also with Java 7 surprisingly): https://github.com/stianh/gradle-jaxb-plugin/issues/20
But I am unable to pass the environment/argument to wsimport/xjc.

How to disable this access or the restriction?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only working solution I found was to set a system property using reflection:

```
task wsimport {
  System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'file')
  ...
}
```

All other solutions using `ext` or `systemProperty` did not work for me.
I have gradle 1.11 installed.

Comment: One longterm concern I see with your gradle task, how will you support multiple versions of wsdl or let say if you have multiple xsds. file does not allow to use wildcard

Comment: Arne,Thanks so much for sharing this , it worked !! very help full