# Gradle Plugin for SonarQube fails with error related to accessExternalSchema

Tags: gradle, sonarqube

For several of our projects, we get the following error, when using the Sonar Gradle plugin (http://docs.sonarqube.org/display/SONAR/Analyzing+with+Gradle).

```
11:26:16.744 ERROR - Error parsing XML: XML InputStream(5) schema_reference: Failed to read schema document 'persistence_1_0.xsd', because 'http' access is not allowed due to restriction set by the accessExternalSchema property.
```

We have run into this previously when running xjc tasks, and I tried to adapt the solution there, resulting in the following:

```
sonarqube {
  System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
}
```

This however, didn't appear to have any effect.

Any suggestions on how to fix the problem?

Thanks!

Comment: Any stacktrace? Can your run same command with `--stacktrace --debug`

Comment: Sure, I ran it with --full-stacktrace --debug, and pasted the log entry to http://pastebin.com/cw0LsAF9

Answer (score 0):

You could maybe try to apply same workaround than [How to surpass gradle wsimport task JDK 8 access restrictions?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22044397/how-to-surpass-gradle-wsimport-task-jdk-8-access-restrictions)

Anyway in SonarQube 5.2 there will be no more database connection so no more persistence.xml.

Comment: We already tried this (with and without being wrapped into allprojects {}), and it had no effect.


    `sonarqube {
      System.setProperty('javax.xml.accessExternalSchema', 'all')
    }`

Comment: When 5.2 is released, and confirmed working, I'll mark this as the answer.  For now, for affected projects, we are using the Gradle project's sonar runner plugin, it doesn't exhibit the same behavior.